# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException -Client shuts down SSL

Tags: java, glassfish-3

HI,

I have a webservice running on glassfish3.1 server on one machine.

On second machine I have a java (GUI) app, that is running and calls the above mentioned web service.

In my webservice call, i send a file as SOAP attachment. It reaches the server, the file is then processed and then it is returned back to my client machine over https.

If my file is too large and takes more than 15 mins, the operation fails and I get the following error:

On Client side: 
**Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly**

on server side:
**javax.servlet.ServletException
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:150)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:184)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:282)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:96)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:618)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:101)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:320)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:168)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:133)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:324)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLOutputWriter.flushChannel(SSLOutputWriter.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SSLOutputBuffer.java:138)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:376)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1241)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLProcessorTask.action(SSLProcessorTask.java:164)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(Output**

...

I think that SSL session is timed out on my client side and not on the server side.

Now I am trying to figure out a way to increase the SSL timeout on my client side which i suppose is 15 mins...

I am not able to do so, any help would be appriciated...
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by SSL "Session"?  It's probably just a connection timeout.  What are you using on the client to make the request?

Comment: I've seen similar errors come up (with and without SSL) when trying to send or receive SOAP messages once they get too big.  I've never really gotten a satisfactory solution other than trimming down my requests.

Comment: Misleading title. There is no evidence here about the client shutting down SSL. Actually it is complaining about the peer doing so incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that SSL session is timed out
>   on my client side

No. Your client encountered a closed (reset) connection without first receiving an SSL close_notify from the server. So it wasn't the client. I would guess that the server is imposing a POST size limit and closing the connection when you exceed it.

If you are sending too much data you are going to experience IOExceptions somewhere or other. Either obey the limit or raise it, and obey the new value.

Comment: As the client is saying "SSL peer shut down incorrectly"[note the term peer] so the problem is there at server side. Secondly, Firewalls have no direct implication on a tunneled connection like SSL, TLS & that's why they are secure. A firewall don't have capability to intercept the SSL and or TLS encapsulated packets[HTTPS, SFTP etc], so how can it get the knowledge of a HTTP-POST size?

Comment: @Puspendu Banerjee of course a firewall has that capability. That's what it's for. SSL or no SSL. I said nothing about intercepting packets. All it has to do is send a TCP RST. And it doesn't have to look at content-length, it can see the packet size in the IP headers, and the segment size in the TCP headers. From the client's point of view if a firewall or router drops a connection it is the same as the peer doing so. However the server appears to be closing its own connection for some reason, possibly something watching the outgoing response size?

Answer (score -1):

Open your domain.xml and try to find out which SSL version you are using.
If you see something like the following one[ **ssl3-enabled="false"** ], then it's SSL2 which has default timeout of 100 seconds.

```
<ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl"  ssl3-enabled="false" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
```

In such a scenario 
either you can put some bigger value to **ssl-session-timeout** property[you may need to add this]

or you may opt for using ssl3 over ssl which has larger value for timeout by default.

Ref: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/abhaq/index.html

Comment: Nothing to do with it. That's an SSL *session* timeout, not a connection or read timeout. It just means that SSL sessions can't be resumed if they are > 100 seconds old (amazing value).

Comment: @Pushkar As the client is saying "SSL peer shut down incorrectly"[note the term peer] so the problem is there at server side

Comment: but not an SSL session problem. SSL session timeouts don't close channels.